# Change Play Pause state of button cell in UITableView with Audio Player in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, audio

I have added audio player in UITableView using https://github.com/jorgenhenrichsen/SwiftAudio this library. Player is working fine but I am having issue in changing the play pause button image in UITableView.

This library has a method which gives the state of audio(play, ready, buffer , failed):

```
 func setPlayButtonState(forAudioPlayerState state: AudioPlayerState) ()
```

This method works fine, and changes Button Image when audio is playing when added in a View Controller. But I have to manage the state in UITableViewCell.

Like this: 
[image]

For changing the cell's button image I have used this method :

```
   func setPlayButtonState(forAudioPlayerState state: AudioPlayerState) () {
       let cell = YOUR_TABLEVIEW_REF.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: YOUR_ROW_FOR_LANGUAGE_CELL, section: YOUR_SECTION_FOR_LANGUAGE_CELL)) as! AppSettingViewCell
     cell.playButton.image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE NAME") 
}
```

It works for one index. But what I need to do is change it to stop state again when some other row has been clicked.

and my configure cell method:

```
func configurePlaylistCell (tableView: UITableView, cell: PlaylistCell, controller: AudioController, indexPath: IndexPath){

    cell.playPauseButton.tag = indexPath.row + 100

    cell.playButtonPressed = { [weak self] (sender: UIButton) in
        self?.indexPathForCell = IndexPath(row: sender.tag - 100 , section: 0)
        if !controller.audioSessionController.audioSessionIsActive {
            try? controller.audioSessionController.activateSession()
        }

        print (controller.player.currentIndex)

        if let item = controller.player.currentItem {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            try? controller.player.load(item: item, playWhenReady: true)
            }else {
                try? controller.player.jumpToItem(atIndex: sender.tag - 100, playWhenReady: true)
            }
        }
        else {
            controller.player.togglePlaying()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save in a property the index of the current playing cell (let's call it X). Than, on tap of that button from another cell (let's call it Y) you can:

- Change the icon on cell X
- Play the Y content

That will cause the state change again, this time for cell Y, so you will change the icon of cell Y.

As a side note I want to warn you that probably you should save the state of all cells in some sort of data structure (like an array) and then use that to dequeue cells in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*, otherwise you could get into some issue when cells start to be more than what you can see in the screen. 
I don't know if you did that already, but wanted to avoid you from ending up in some other trouble later.

EDIT:

Assuming that controller.player.currentIndex is the (optional) index of the cell playing) it would look something like this:

```swift
    func configurePlaylistCell (tableView: UITableView, cell: PlaylistCell, controller: AudioController, indexPath: IndexPath){

    cell.playPauseButton.tag = indexPath.row + 100

    cell.playButtonPressed = { [weak self] (sender: UIButton) in
        self?.indexPathForCell = IndexPath(row: sender.tag - 100 , section: 0)
        if !controller.audioSessionController.audioSessionIsActive {
            try? controller.audioSessionController.activateSession()
        }

        print (controller.player.currentIndex)

        if let item = controller.player.currentItem {
            if let index = controller.player.currentIndex, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: YOUR_SECTION_FOR_LANGUAGE_CELL)) as! AppSettingViewCell {
               cell.playButton.image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE NAME") 
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            try? controller.player.load(item: item, playWhenReady: true)
            }else {
                try? controller.player.jumpToItem(atIndex: sender.tag - 100, playWhenReady: true)
            }
        }
        else {
            controller.player.togglePlaying()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @encricoza - Can you share some code for this logic please ? As I have tried it but could get it right

Comment: @ios hard to do without some more code from you. If you share with me the code of the viewController I can try to edit it for you

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look @enricoza

Comment: @enricoza- this code will not reset other button state. e.g:- If I firstly click on button at index 0, and then click on button at index 1, it should change image of 0 index as well (to play image).

Comment: @ios the part I added should be just what you want.
Assuming that controller.player.currentIndex is the previous index, once you tap on some different raw it will reset the image on the currentIndex, and then change the current index with that jumpToItem call just below that.

Comment: @ios that's really not that helpful... you could explain why it doesn't work (does the currentIndex means what I'm assuming it means? Is it the correct value at the time of call? What happens if you put a breakpoint at that line? Does it even compile?) and maybe provide some more context (like the full view controller) or a sample project to test. Unfortunately I can't deduct all this info from your answer/comments...

Comment: @enricoza- yes current index is the index of currently playing track. But there is a toggle option in that library as well which resume or play track from the same position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207115/discussion-between-enricoza-and-ios).